# functional analysis: show L^1 integral operator has norm 1

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

I just started my course in functional analysis and have already stumbled across some things I don't understand, which are quite basic :(. 
In my lecture notes it says:
Let $\mu$ be a measure on a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathscr F)$. We define the operator $Q: L^1(\mu) \to \Bbb R$, by $Q(f)=\int_{\Omega} f d\mu$, for $f \in L^1(\mu)$. It follows that the operator $Q$ is linear and boundend and has norm 1.

I have already verified linear and bounded. However, I get stuck on showing that it has norm 1. Here is what I have done:

$\lVert Q(f)\rVert= sup_{f \in L^1(\mu)}\lvert \int_{\Omega} f d\mu\rvert \le sup_{f \in L^1(\mu)}\int_{\Omega}\lvert  f \rvert d\mu = \lVert f \rVert_{L^1(\mu)}$, thus $\lVert Q(f)\rVert \le 1$.

Now, I do not really understand how to tackle the reverse inequality. I was hoping perhaps someone could help me understand this basic notion.

Thanks a lot and wish you a good day.

Frederique

Comment: This is the definition. You input all vectors of norm 1 into the operator and take the sup. But then just choosing a positive function gives the value 1 which is also clearly an upper bound since

$$\left|\int_\Omega f\right|\le\int_\Omega |f|$$

Comment: Dear Adam, thank you for your quick comment! I tried doing that indeed in the upper part, however I got stuck on showing that ||Q(f)||>=1. Do you have any suggestions for that? I'm not sure how to show this. Am I supposed to randomly plug in a function for f?

Comment: Since the value of the norm is a supremum over all functions of norm 1, you just need to show one single function has

$$\left|\int_\Omega f\right|\ge 1$$

But that's easy, pick **any** norm-$1$ $f$ which is positive, then

$$1=\int f = \int|f|$$

So equality is achieved and the sup is at least as big as every possibility so $\lVert Q\rVert\ge 1$.

Comment: Dear Adam, thanks again. Do I understand correctly; I need a single function f in L^1 whose norm is 1: $\int|f|=1$. At the same time: $\left|\intf\right|\ge 1$. Everytime I have $\|intf|\ge 1$, I don't have that $\int|f|=1$ and vice versa. You said that if I pick any norm-1 function which is positive, it should follow. I'm afraid I don't fully understand how to find that norm-1 function which gives both $\|intf|\ge 1$ and $\int|f|=1$, without automatically being equal. PS: hope the editing didn't go wrong, if so, terribly sorry!

Comment: The equality **is** indeed automatic, but it doesn't matter! That's the beauty of it. Sure you only need to show that the other inequality holds, but equality is a special case of an inequality! To find such an $f$ is easy, if $f$ is your norm $1$ function, then $|f|$ is your positive norm 1 function. :-)